# first-of-type and first-line

Tags: css

Is the weight of first-line greater than that of first-of-type? I'm a little confused!

```css
p::first-line {
  color: green;
}

p:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}

h1:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div>
     
<p>p1contentp1contentp1contentp1contentp1<br>contentp1contentp1contentp1content</p>
      <h1>h1hahaha</h1>
      <h1>h1hahaha2</h1>
      <p>p2content</p>
    </div>
```

**In my opinion, the first p-text should be completely blue.**

Comment: the title should be CSS first-of-type and first-line

Comment: if i add 
p {
  display: inline;
}

the first p-text will be completely blue

Comment: Note that you can always [edit] your post if you need to

Comment: You should not *force* a tag into your title. [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 4):

`::first-line` is a *pseudo element*, which means that it behaves as if it is an element inside its parent, the `p`.

So CSS properties defined on the `p` don't even apply to the `::first-line`, unless they are inherited.
In this case, the `color` property does inherit, but it is simply overridden by the `color` of the pseudo element.